# in MYSQL select query reuse one of the selected column

Tags: mysql, sql

ySo here is my psuedo query.

```
Select `bigformula` as BIGQUERY, BIGQUERY*100 as percent from mytable group by employee_id
```

I am selecting and computing a bunch of things to derive `BIGQUERY`. Now i want to reuse `BIGQUERY` in the same select statment. How do i do that?

Currently if i run the above column it gives:

`Error Code: 1054`
Unknown column 'BIGQUERY' in 'field list'

What other tricks can i use to achieve the same? Will there be a major performance drag with any of these trick. Please note that all the columns used in the query are indexed already and things are runing pretty quick so the indexes do work.

Comment: Just use the formula again (the server doesn't mind), or wrap BIGQUERY up as a subquery.

Comment: @Strawberry Reusing the formula makes the code harder to maintain as you have two copies of the same business rule. I regret having no "SQL-macro" that would avoid that (using `FUNCTION` makes query so utterly slow that it's often not usable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
Select subquery.BIGQUERY, subquery.BIGQUERY*100 as percent
FROM 
(
  Select `bigformula` as BIGQUERY
  From mytable
) subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

```
select @v := `bigformula` as BIGQUERY, @v*100 as percent
from mytable;
```

When there is `GROUP BY`

```
select employee_id, BIGQUERY, BIGQUEY*100 as percent
from (
  select employee_id, `bigformula` as BIGQUERY
  from mytable
  group by employee_id) a;
```

Comment: Get `null` for the percent column the first time i run this. After that the variable always has the data of the last row. Added `Group by` statement to my question

Comment: @codeNinja, I'm afraid subquery would be the cleanest way. answer has been updated

Comment: User defined variable has many problem, I always get the value from previous query. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/

Comment: No, it's not recommended to set user-defined variables (`@thing`) outside a `SET` statement, as it's not guaranteed to work (order of columns evaluation might change), and MySQL might drop this feature someday: "Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html